# dse cassandra solr doesnt return _uniqueKey in response

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Im using Datastax 4.6. My solr client queries data by using _uniqueKey. From version 4.6 the limitation about using simple primary key is removed. How can i configure solr or create table in cassandra, so that I receive in solr response information about synthetic key _uniqueKey. There is no problem when i use compound keys, only with simple.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS unitable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unitable (
    "depId" INT PRIMARY KEY,
    "parentId" INT,
    "name" text
);
```

INSERT INTO unitable ( "depId", "parentId", "name" ) 
VALUES 
( 689, 2, 'test' );

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieIntField" name="TrieIntField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="depId" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="name" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="parentId" stored="true" type="TrieIntField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>depId</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

no _uniqueKey in response

```
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">5</int>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="1.0">
  <doc>
    <int name="depId">689</int>
    <str name="name">test</str>
    <int name="parentId">2</int></doc>
</result>
</response>
```

Comment: "depId" is your unique key and I see the same in your response.

Comment: I need a way to somehow configure solr, to return synthetic key and its value. Same as it does with compound PKs. As you see in response with simple PK there's no such info(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The synthetic _uniqueKey field is generated and returned only when using compound keys; in case of simple keys, the key field is directly used.